# How to run a specific scipy test

Tags: python, scipy

I have been running the scipy test suite in pypy. My test code is simply:

```
import scipy
scipy.test('full', verbose = 2)
```

It fails at

```
test_basic (test_signaltools.TestOrderFilt)
```

If I now want to run only that test, how would I do that? I tried changing the test line to`scipy.test('test_signaltools.TestOrderFilt')` and various other options but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, you can use `nosetests path/to/file:name_of_test_class.test_func`

EDIT: From the interpreter, you can run tests for a specific subpackage via e.g.

```
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> signal.test(verbose=2)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. The only file is the one containing import scipy
scipy.test('full', verbose = 2) . Say it is called scipy-test.py. Should I do `nosetests ./scipy-test.py:test_signaltools.TestOrderFilt` ?

Comment: In other words, which file is "path/to/file" referring to?

Comment: No. It's `<path-of-scipy-install>/scipy/signal/tests/test_signal tools.py`